# Tensorflow 2.0 OOM after a few steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am running the following code

```
for step, (batch, _) in enumerate(batcher.iter_batches(batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True), 1):
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        logits, *_ = model(batch)
        loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits[:, :-1, :], labels=batch[:, 1:])
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

    grads = g.gradient(loss, model.variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(list(zip(grads, model.variables)))
```

The confusing thing is that this runs for several steps before ending up crashing due to the GPU memory being exhausted. Each batch is exactly the same size, and the model is not dynamic (although it is executed with eager execution). The optimizer does allocate some parameters based on the variables being updated, but since those variables are the same each step, it should crash during the first step as far as I can tell.

Is there some way I can ensure that un-needed data is evicted from the GPU before the next step perhaps?

Comment: Hi @Davis Yoshida, can you please include a minimum reproducible code that can reproduce your error? and also include details about your hardware (ie. GPU memory).

Comment: Did you solve this? I"m facing the same issue

Comment: @Crispy13 Never figured it out, just had to use a smaller model IIRC. Unfortunately I couldn't really post a minimal example since the model code was quite large.